# Configuring MySQL's mysqlsh to accept SQL and connect by default

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I configure the MySQL 8.0.15 shell. I just downloaded it and I am already having problems.

1. When I run the shell program I always have to switch from MySQL JS to MySQL SQL
2. I always have to reconnect using `\connect root@localhost`

I would like to open the MySQL shell and just get to work without having to do those two things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start the shell with `mysqlsh --sql --uri=myname@localhost` it will accept SQL commands directly.

If you need only to use SQL you may wish to consider using the [ancient and honorable `mysql` command line client program](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-getting-started/en/#mysql-getting-started-connecting).   `mysql  -h localhost -u myname`